# res/color/filename.xml resource file not found on real android device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, gradle, android-resources

In an android project a custom color resource file created to change the background color of disabled button.
Added a resource file **/res/color/app_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorDisabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary"  />
</selector>
```

Used this resource in style **/res/valus/styles.xml**

```
<style name="Button" parent="TextFont">
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_color</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">370dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">40dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Used the style in a layout like below:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/Button"
            android:layout_width="392dp"
            android:text="@string/withdraw_in_cash"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
```

This code is working fine with simulated **Nexus 5X API 29x86**, but for the real device (moto e 6s) it crashes with an error like a blow:

```
2020-06-16 22:48:09.053 12963-12963/com.ans.realtimeredemption E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ans.realtimeredemption, PID: 12963
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ans.realtimeredemption/com.ans.realtimeredemption.SelectRedemptionType}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1871)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6760)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class Button
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.ans.realtimeredemption:color/app_color with resource ID #0x7f05001a
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/app_color.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f05001a
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:869)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:648)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:897)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:955)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5022)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:892)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:166)
        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:141)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:71)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:67)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:187)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:110)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:774)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:880)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:841)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:841)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:841)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:883)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:841)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.ans.realtimeredemption.SelectRedemptionType.onCreate(SelectRedemptionType.java:18)
2020-06-16 22:48:09.057 12963-12963/com.ans.realtimeredemption E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2959)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1871)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6760)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #3: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:190)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1332)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1291)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:855)
            ... 45 more
```

Emulator Details:

```
Name: Nexus_5X_API_29_x86

CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Sowvik Roy\.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_29_x86.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 29)

Skin: nexus_5x

SD Card: 800M

Snapshot: no

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 1920

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: Nexus 5X

vm.heapSize: 256

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.gps: yes

image.androidVersion.api: 29

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-29\google_apis\x86\

tag.id: google_apis

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: Nexus_5X_API_29_x86

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 420

avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5X API 29 x86

hw.arc: false

hw.gpu.mode: auto

snapshot.present: no

hw.device.hash2: MD5:ae200ad6786ec467cb9067f7b46b0fd1

hw.ramSize: 1536

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: false

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 800M

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

The screenshot of the structure is attached below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **app_color.xml** file from this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorDisabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary"  />
</selector>
```

To this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@color/colorDisabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
        <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"  />
    </selector>
```

You are supposed to use **drawable** not **color**

Hope you got a difference...

Comment: Still, one question why it was running smoothly in an emulator?

Comment: Emulator details added to the question.

Comment: I will update my answer if I find any useful info l related to it